# installed java, but java -version not showing new java

Tags: centos, java, path

I just installed jdk1.6.0. I have tried multiple ways to set the path variable and make java 1.6 my new running version. And nothing is working. Running centos5 virtual machine.

alternatives --config java returns the following:

```
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
```

java -version returns the following:

```
java version "1.4.2_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_19-b04, mixed mode)
```

echo $PATH returns the following:

```
/root/bin:/opt/j2sdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/testing/jdk1.6.0_23/bin:/usr/local/testing/jdk1.6.0_23/bin
```

1.6.0 is installed in the following location: /usr/local/testing/jdk1.6.0_23/bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out. I just appended the new java path to the beginning of my path variable instead of the end and it worked.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/testing/jdk1.6.0_23/bin:$PATH
```

That worked. Now i am going to set in my script so it will do automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `/opt/j2sdk/bin` and `/usr/local/testing/jdk1.6.0_23/bin` from your `PATH`.

When you ran `alternatives --config`, it should have changed `/usr/bin/java` to point to the 1.6.0 version.

If you add them to `PATH` and are using `alternatives`, you will have two places to configure things, and it will get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 or RHEL 7: I faced this problem while installing pycharm-community-2017.1.4 on RHEL 7.1. Error was:

```
Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_75-mockbuild_2015_01_16_09_12-b00: Java 1.8 or later is required
```

I Found that the required version of java is installed but not detected.then I searched over internet and Used the following to resolve this problem:

```
# alternatives --config java
```

output:

```
Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64 /jre/bin/java
   2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
 + 3           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.31-2.b13.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java
   4           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Now enter the number of your desired version and press enter key as follows:

```
Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:4
```

Check Java version:

```
# java -version
```

Output:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```