# install java sdk 6, wheezy

Tags: software-installation, java, debian

Followed  [debian Java Sun wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun%20debian%20wiki%20-%20Java%20!), and later [1](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun%20debian%20wiki%20-%20Java%20!)[open jsk 7 ][2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35185/installing-openjdk-7-jdk-does-not-update-java-which-is-still-version-1-6/35214#35214) which has a note on installing 6 : link to [java 7 on debian](http://alexander.holbreich.org/2011/11/java-7-on-debian/)

> aptitude install sun-java6-jdk
>
> No candidate version found for sun-java6-jdk No candidate version
>   found for sun-java6-jdk No packages will be installed, upgraded, or
>   removed. 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
>   upgraded. Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be
>   used.

Then I downloaded the [Java sdk bin file](http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1376158431_2824ea2f44fded756812deea0a550eb4) (should i download the rpm bin?)

Opened terminal again, su ed and typed make but get error no make! How do I get make?
How do I install Java 6 sdk?

Update:

bins are just scripts with attachments. They are installer.

Just :

> cd to folder
>   su
>   (enter password)
>   chmod 755 xxx.bin
>   ./xx.bin

This executes the script and it extracts to a folder jdk1.6.0_45 in the current folder. Now what?

Comment: when i type make, error msg is 'bash: make: command not found
'

Comment: seems you don't have make and maybe no (g)cc installed. You might run `apt-get install make gcc` to install make before running it

Comment: thanks executing that earlier tried to get make from software add remove

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it was a newbie question, bins are just scripts with attachments (More precisely 'bins' are *binary* packages, as opposed to source packages. This includes stuff you install via apt-get (which is compiled by debian) and oracle javas (which are compiled by oracle for either 32 or 64 bit linux) The aha moment for me was that i do not need to run them as a parameter to another command but they are self running scripts/ like on mac - you can untar or jar extract them}.

make-jpkg needs to be installed, not a typo! See https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage

New Debian install so had to get some good to have's like

> apt-get install make gcc

(gcc not required for java but I expect I will need it in the future when I try to build a c++ a

and

> apt-get install java-package

(needed this)

Make the package

> make-jpkg jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin

And install it

> dpkg -i oracle-j2sdk1.7_1.7.0+update2_amd64.deb

Choose which version should be the default :

> sudo update-java-alternatives -s j2sdk1.7-oracle

where 'j2sdk1.7-oracle' is the folder where it was installed in your installation .

I had su ed before make-jpkg jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin

> You are real root -- unfortunately, some Java distributions have
>   install scripts that directly manipulate /etc, and may cause some
>   inconsistencies on your system. Instead, you should become a non-root
>   user and run:
>
> fakeroot make-jpkg jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>
> which will allow no damage to be done to your system files and still
>   permit the Java distribution to successfully extract.

Got to love linux - looking over your shoulder.

After fakeroot

Gave the command again. Response :

> Detected Debian build architecture: amd64 Detected Debian GNU type:
>   x86_64-linux-gnu
>
> Detected product:
>       Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK)
>       Standard Edition, Version 1.6.0+update45
>       Oracle(TM), Inc. Is this correct [Y/n]:

Press y ; Then took a few minutes unpacking and repackaging, a lot of warnings but worked.

Finally prompted me to run command, as root :

> dpkg -i oracle-j2sdk1.6_1.6.0+update45_amd64.deb

After doing that java version gives me the correct version - sdk 1.6_45 :

> java -version
>
> java version "1.6.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: 'bins' are not "just scripts with attachments" -- they're *bin*ary packages, as opposed to source packages.  This includes stuff you install via apt-get (which is compiled by debian) and oracle javas (which are compiled by oracle for either 32 or 64 bit linux).  I'm dubious that this requires `make` and `gcc`: are they prereqs of `java-package`?  They certainly won't actually be used in this process.  +1 for the general tip about `java-package` and hopefully you correct/edit this.  You do realize this installs java 7, not java 6?

Comment: @goldilocks yes your right i just copied that from the wiki. Now its the real commands for java 6 current version. thanks so much for pointing them out.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install Oracle Java JDK 7 which is newer version ?

To intall Java Runtime Environment on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

> apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

To intall package to developing programs using Java on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

> apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Source: http://namhuy.net/1195/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-7.html