# java -version and $JAVA_HOME display wrong information

Tags: linux, rhel, java

I have a RHEL 7 server.
Installed java version is `jdk1.8.0_151`

```
# ls -l /usr/java
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 255 Apr 24 14:10 jdk1.8.0_151
```

I set `JAVA_HOME` location and added `bin` directory to `PATH` variable in `/etc/profile`

```
# grep JAVA_HOME /etc/profile
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Still `java -version` shows false information and `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows no output.

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
# 
# echo $JAVA_HOME

#
```

How can I resolve this?

#### Update

When executed the following commands `java -version` and `echo $JAVA_HOME` works for the user `igwuser`, but doesn't work when logged in as root.

```
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/"
```

When logged in as `root`,

```
[igwuser@dep4 ~]$ sudo su
[root@dep4 igwuser]# java -version
bash: java: command not found...
[root@dep4 igwuser]# echo $JAVA_HOME

[root@dep4 igwuser]#
```

Why it doesn't work when logged in as root?

#### Update 2

`PATH` variable resets when I log in and logout. That should be the issue.

```
[root@dep4 igwuser]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[root@dep4 igwuser]# 
[root@dep4 igwuser]# 
[root@dep4 igwuser]# export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:$PATH
[root@dep4 igwuser]# echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[root@dep4 igwuser]# 
[root@dep4 igwuser]# exit
exit
[igwuser@dep4 ~]$ sudo su
[root@dep4 igwuser]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[root@dep4 igwuser]#
```

Comment: Did you log out and log in again after the changes?

Comment: What are the outputs of `which java` (and `type java` if you use bash)? Did you check that there is actually a `java` executable in `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Yes

Comment: @xenoid: `which java ` =  `/bin/java` , `type java` = `java is /bin/java` , `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java -version` = `java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)`

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7160/5132 again, with a bit of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82991/5132 thrown in.

Comment: @JdeBP: unix.stackexchange.com/q/7160/5132 didn't help. That's why I posted the question

Comment: I don't believe that you tried the answers there, or even what was laid out in that question, because if you had, you'd have shown in _this_ question how you looked up the alternatives to show that they weren't the problem.

Comment: @JdeBP: I updated the question. Please check

Comment: @HaukeLaging: for igwuser >>> `$ echo $PATH` = `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151//bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/igwuser/.local/bin:/home/igwuser/bin` for root user >>> `# echo $PATH` = `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

Comment: When I log out and log in, `PATH` variable resets only for root user. Why is that?

Comment: Check how `/etc/profile` is called. May be different for different users or different shells.

Answer (score 1):

I was editing the wrong file(`/etc/profile`) all that time. Adding following lines to `/etc/bashrc` resolved the issue.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172-amd64/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Thanks

> Update : Please refer the comment by @jsbillings below. creating a custom script in `/etc/profile.d/` and adding above lines is the most recommended.

Comment: You really should be putting a .sh file in /etc/profile.d/ rather than editing /etc/bashrc.

Comment: @jsbillings: Thanks for the comment. Why is editing `/etc/bashrc` not recommended?

Comment: You want the OS to be able to update that file, since it is owned by a package. Modifying it will prevent the “bash” package from ever updating that file.

Comment: @jsbillings : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568921/java-home-doesnt-direct-to-latest-java-installation

Answer (score 0):

1. Each user has his own variable environment. Thus, it's normal that values of `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables are different from one user (root) to another one (non-root user).
2. A persistent way to save environment variables :

   - Add your environment variable by editing `~/.bashrc` file : `vim ~/.bashrc`
   - Load the changes you did in `~/.bashrc` using : `source ~/.bashrc`